# How do Black-Hole singularity and Heisenberg uncertainty principal can co-exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

According to relativity, Black-holes bends the spacetime in a fashion that the curvature goes infinite and becomes a single point, so the mass collapse to a single point, so density goes infinite as the body has no volume, no dimensions to wiggle around. On the other hand, its location now is determined, hence its momentum goes to infinity. This relation seems impossible to me. You see, I can not avoid to conclude that would create circular reference where the energy would forever increase so would its mass. Can you help me understand what I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do black holes violate the uncertainty principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193954/)

Comment: See also [An electron falling into a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45051/)