# Doesn't the uncertainty principle stop matter from collapsing to a point?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I just read a question about degeneracy pressure and collapsing white dwarfs. When the dwarfs have a certain mass (say that they have become fat dwarfs) the degeneracy pressure will lose the battle with gravity and collapse to a neutron star. Which in its turn, if it has eaten enough, will collapse into a black hole. All the particles constituting the neutron star will end up at a point, theoretically. Won't the uncertainty principle prevent the last stage of this collapse? Won't some kind of "uncertainty pressure" appear?

What I ask is not if the uncertainty principle applies to a black hole that has already formed (as does the question of which this is supposed to be a duplicate). I ask if the UP doesn't prevent the collapse to a hole.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do black holes violate the uncertainty principle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193954/)

Comment: My understanding is that a black hole does not have to be a single point.  Pack enough mass within what's called the mass's Schwarschild radius -- which is a finite distance -- and it will become a black hole.  Now, what happens after, as the mass continues to collapse, I don't know.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm not sure. The question is about a black hole that has already formed 9if the UP can be applied to it). I'm asking about the process of the formation, not about the bh itself. Of course, black holes require a quantized version of spacetime, but won't the UP kick in when the spacetime is still smooth (non-quantized)?

Comment: The black hole is a single, rather heavy particle. You may appply UP to any physical object INCLUDING a black hole with no significant risk to run into paradox.

Comment: @fraxinus I'm not asking though if the UP applies to a black hole that's already been formed. I ask if the UP doesn't stop the (still separate) particles from *forming* a BH.

Comment: Yes, it does - up to a limit. The degeneracy pressure emerges from the UP.

Comment: @fraxinus Why are degeneracy pressure and the UP connected? The UP applies to single particles while the DP applies to the whole.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/638992/2451

Comment: Hi Deschele Schilder. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic Hi there! I made an edit of my previous question. I made it clear (also in a comment that asked if the linked question answered mine) that it wasn't a duplicate of the linked question. Should I have waited longer?