# Why isn't the formation of a black hole stopped by the uncertainty priciple?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

As long as spacetime is smooth (that is, not quantized), the uncertainty principle can be applied. When a black hole forms the particles that are collapsing get closer and closer (though the metric of space changes). Won't the uncertainty principle prevent them (the particles) from approaching each other too close? That is as long if the spacetime is still smooth. Or will the changing metric prevent this? I'm not asking if the uncertainty principle can be applied to an already formed black hole (if it can be formed), which it obviously can't due to the non-existence of a quantum theory of spacetime. I'm asking if the UP can be applied to the particles that are collapsing to a BH.

Comment: Black holes are classical objects. Uncertainty principle is a quantum statement. We do not yet have any quantum theory of gravity so as it currently stands, the uncertainty principle cannot be applied to black holes.

Comment: @safesphere But doesn't this mean that the particles reach a velocity close to the speed of light? Which could prevent the particles from collapsing as this is the speed to hover beneath the event horizon? So won't the particles hover under a surface just above them? In which case the singularity hasn't been formed yet (which doesn't mean that a black hole hasn't formed). In which case I could better have asked if the formation of a singularity can be stopped by the UP.

Comment: @safesphere I’m not. It is possible to discuss quantum mechanics and black holes together but one has to be extremely careful. Looking at the wording of question, it seemed to me that for the level of the question asked, my comment was the best possible correct answer.

Comment: @PraharMitra I stated in my question that the UP can be applied as long the spacetime is smooth (non-quantized).  I'm not asking if the UP can be applied to the black hole when fully formed (it can't,) but if it can be applied to the collapsing particles.

Comment: @safesphere Why can't particles with near-light-speed escape a neutron star? And has the spacetime already a singularity before all particles have collapsed?

Comment: A subtle point is that the surfaces of neutron stars and white dwarfs do not consist of relativistic particles, otherwise they would escape. Note also that the collapse happens inside out. The collapse timescales are shorter for higher densities.

Answer (score 5):

The uncertainty principle does not prevent indistinguishable fermions getting arbitrarily close. All it says is that if they do, they must have an arbitrarily large difference in momentum (or different spin quantum numbers).

In other words, you can cram *ideal* (i.e. non-interacting, point-like) fermions to as large a density as you like, but the Fermi momentum then becomes commensurately large.

If the fermions become ultra-relativistic then their equation of state becomes $ P \propto \rho$, which is incapable of providing hydrostatic equilibrium (which requires $P \propto \rho^\alpha$ with $\alpha >4/3$, or even higher in a General Relativistic treatment).

Comment: I understand. But if the momentum of the particles approaches infinity, their velocity will approach the velocity of light. Which would mean that they could "hover", like light beneath the event horizon. If the singularity hasn't yet formed, this means that they could stop to collapse due to this velocity.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Momentum isn't linearly proportional to velocity at relativistic speeds. The Lorentz factor continues to increase. Ultra-relativistic degenerate fermions are incapable of providing hydrostatic equilibrium.  Nothing hovers inside the event horizon; everything, including light moves inwards.

Comment: Why can't light rays perpendicular to the horizon, hoover beneath it?

Comment: @safesphere But what about the sideward direction? If I point my flashlight "parallel" to the surface, won't the light hover? Space ($r$) and time have interchanged, so the singularity formed can be an infinite line (as time can extend to infinity beneath the horizon).  But is this singularity already there before all particles have collapsed? Do these particles "follow" the spacetime of a singularity, or is the singularity formed when all particles are on top of each other (i.e., have zero spatial distance to each other)?